# How to validate input[type="date] in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

*There is a component:*

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const EditIntern = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [intern, setIntern] = useState([]);
  const [name, inputName] = useState("");
  const [email, inputEmail] = useState("");
  const [start, inputStart] = useState("");
  const [end, inputEnd] = useState("");

  const [errorNameEmpty, isErrorNameEmpty] = useState(true);
  const [errorEmailEmpty, isErrorEmailEmpty] = useState(true);
  const [errorEmailValid, iserrorEmailValid] = useState(false);
  const [errorStartEmpty, isErrorStartEmpty] = useState(true);
  const [errorEndEmpty, isErrorEndEmpty] = useState(true);

  const validEmail = new RegExp(
    /(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)/gm
  );

  const dateValidate = () => {
    if (start.value > end.value) {
      console.log("Start > end");
      console.log(start.valueAsNumber);
      console.log(end.valueAsNumber);
    } else {
      console.log("Ok");
      console.log(start.valueAsNumber);
      console.log(end.valueAsNumber);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchIntern = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/interns/${id}`);
      const intern = await response.json();
      setIntern(intern);
    };
    fetchIntern();
    console.log(`I want to get intern with id: ${id}!`);
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div>
      <NavLink to="/">Back to list </NavLink>
      <form>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => {
            if (e.target.value === "") {
              isErrorNameEmpty(true);
            } else {
              isErrorNameEmpty(false);
            }
            inputName(e.target.value);
          }}
          onClick={(e) => {
            if (e.target.value === "") {
              isErrorNameEmpty(true);
            }
          }}
        />
        {errorNameEmpty ? <span>Name can't be empty</span> : <></>}

        <label>Email</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => {
            if (e.target.value === "") {
              isErrorEmailEmpty(true);
            } else if (!validEmail.test(e.target.value)) {
              iserrorEmailValid(true);
              isErrorEmailEmpty(false);
            } else {
              iserrorEmailValid(false);
              isErrorEmailEmpty(false);
            }
            inputEmail(e.target.value);
          }}
          onClick={(e) => {
            if (e.target.value === "") {
              isErrorEmailEmpty(true);
            }
          }}
        />
        {errorEmailEmpty ? <span>Email can't be empty</span> : <></>}
        {errorEmailValid ? <span>Example: email@gmail.com</span> : <></>}

        <label>Start date</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          name="email"
          value={start}
          onChange={(e) => {
            if (e.target.value === "") {
              isErrorStartEmpty(true);
            } else {
              isErrorStartEmpty(false);
            }
            inputStart(e.target.value);
          }}
          onClick={(e) => {
            if (e.target.value === "") {
              isErrorStartEmpty(true);
            }
          }}
        />
        {errorStartEmpty ? <span>Start date can't be empty</span> : <></>}

        <label>End date</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          name="email"
          value={end}
          onChange={(e) => {
            inputEnd(e.target.value);
            if (e.target.value === "") {
              isErrorEndEmpty(true);
            } else {
              isErrorEndEmpty(false);
            }
            dateValidate();
          }}
          onClick={(e) => {
            if (e.target.value === "") {
              isErrorEndEmpty(true);
            }
          }}
        />
        {errorEndEmpty ? <span>End date can't be empty</span> : <></>}

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>

      <h2>{intern.name}</h2>
      <h2>{intern.email}</h2>
      <h2>{intern.internshipStart}</h2>
      <h2>{intern.internshipEnd}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditIntern;
```

**It has two inputs of type date. The task is to check that the start date is not greater than the end date.
I created a dateValidate function for this (which doesn't work as it should).**

*How can you solve this problem? (Perhaps my approach to form validation is generally not correct, I’ll be happy to read about my mistakes)*

Answer (score 2):

first select right property

```js
// inputEnd(e.target.value);
if (!isNaN(e.target.valueAsNumber)) inputStart(e.target.valueAsNumber);

// ...
//...

// inputEnd(e.target.value);
if (!isNaN(e.target.valueAsNumber)) inputEnd(e.target.valueAsNumber);
```

then validate

```js
// ..when user submits start validation
const onFormSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  // ... 
  
  if (start < end) { 
     // blah blah....
  }
}
```

or better add min and max value so you dont have to check all

```html
    <input type="date" name="start" min="2017-01-01" max="2022-01-01">
```

also please dont use `onChage` with `onClick` event listeners its *very bad* practice
use either one of them, in this case onChage is pretty good.

seems use are using `onClick` for validating, use `useEffect` for validating and keep separate state for errors (object).

and check more options here [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) and play around with devtools (right click on element, select use in console option and see what properties it holds)

Answer (score 0):

transform start date and end date to milliseconds `new Date(start date).getTime()` than compare it (>, <, >=) to the end date also transformed into milliseconds

Comment: ```const dateValidate = () => {
    let startDate = new Date(start).getTime();
    let endDate = new Date(end).getTime();

    if (startDate < endDate) {
      console.log("Start > end");
      console.log(startDate);
      console.log(endDate);
    } else {
      console.log("Ok");
      console.log(startDate);
      console.log(endDate);
    }
  };```

now console.log(endDate) outputs a minus (-) value

Comment: yes you need to switch them, because current time is bigger than yesterday time, (.getTime()) is time in milliseconds since 1970

Comment: You are right, but the function still does not work correctly, maybe it's a call?